# Do I have to create a new user in Google Workspace to create a shared inbox?

Tags: gmail, google-account, email, google-workspace-for-business

I have set up a Google Workspace with 3 users having a unique email.

I also want an email "info@domain.com" that goes into a separate inbox that we all can collaborate on.

Will I have to add a new user for this? I thought that a collaborative inbox group might be the solution for this, but it seems like that is more intended for internal communication

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. The answer is yes. If you need further help please add more details about why do you think that this could be different.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply @Rubén - creating a user gives you access to a lot of functionality in Google Workspace, so given that this "user" doesn't need any of the functionality, other than the ability to receive emails, I thought it might not be neccesary to dedicate a license to that. Thanks again :)

Comment: You can turn off all the services that are not required by this account. If the service is included in the Google Workspace license this will not save you any money only those that might require an additional license will do that.